# Shaded area between line and x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am coloring an area between a line as shown in the graph here.

[image]
However, the shaded area exceeds in some places the line as well as the x-axis.

What is the best way to define the `geom_area` only to the specific areas under/ above the line?

Here is the code to generate the graph:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(quantmod)

data.start.date <- "1990-01-01"

#temporary fix for FRED address change [only needed on MAC computers]
# options(download.file.method="libcurl")

# get symbols from FRED and convert to data frame
var.list <- c("IR", "IQ")
getSymbols(var.list, src="FRED")
ir.df <- data.frame(date= index(IR),IR$IR)
iq.df <- data.frame(date= index(IQ),IQ$IQ)

df <- dplyr::left_join(ir.df, iq.df, by = "date")

# Shorten dataframe, starting as defined above
df = dplyr::filter(df, date >= data.start.date) 

# calculate trade balance (exports-imports)
df$tradebal <- df$IQ-df$IR

ggplot(data = df)+
        geom_line(aes(x=date, y=tradebal, color="Trade Balance"),size=1.2) +
        geom_area(aes(x=date, y=tradebal, fill=tradebal>0), alpha=.4)
```

Comment: if you can do this easily you could add a datapoint for every time `geom_line` intersects `y=0`.

Comment: I am playing around with the duplicate example, but it seems to be a little different when you have monthly data on the x-axis.

Comment: @Wolf If you think it's different, the best thing you can do is: (1) add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), (2) nominate it for reopening and (3) ping me & MrFlick to let us know you have done so.